# Angular ng-href with Split method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a recursive variable with value

```
path = <d:URL>http://www.google.com, Google</d:URL>
```

I want to bind this path in to angular component. I am trying to use the below method to bind the ng-href value.

```
<a ng-href="{{path.URL.split(",")[0]}}" target="_blank">{{path.URL.split(",")[1]}}</a>
```

It seems this breaks with the href but the split gets evaluated for the link title. How can I resolve this.

Thanks.

Comment: I have a recursion as ng-repeat="path in $ctrl.paths"

Comment: simply change single quotes insde of `split` method. `ng-href="{{path.URL.split(',')[0]}}"`

Comment: Thanks num8er you are correct it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem caused by double quotes that breaks `ng-href` when html is outputted but not handled by angular and it becomes:

```
ng-href="{{path.URL.split("
```

So simply change double quotes inside of `split` to single quotes:

```
<ul ng-controller="PathsController as $ctrl">
  <li ng-repeat="path in $ctrl.paths">
    <a 
      ng-href="{{ path.URL.split(',')[0].replace('<d:URL>', '') }}"
    >
      {{ path.URL.split(",")[1].replace('</d:URL>', '') }}
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to perform the split functionality. So try like this

**HTML**:

```
 <a ng-href="{{createURL()}}" target="_blank">{{path.URL.split(",")[1]}}</a>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.createURL=function(path){
  return path.URL.split(",")[0]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

create a function and perform the split operations

```
  $scope.getSplitVal = function(url){
     return url.split(",")[1]
  }
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
  $scope.path = "<d:URL>http://www.google.com, Google</d:URL>"

  $scope.getSplitVal = function(url){
     return url.split(",")[1]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <a ng-href="{{getSplitVal(path)}}" target="_blank">{{getSplitVal(path)}}</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do any string manipulations into controller and not in HTML. Its not good practice.

The string `"<d:URL>http://www.google.com, Google</d:URL>"` should go to:

```
var path = "<d:URL>http://www.google.com, Google</d:URL>";

 $scope.path = {
   URL:{
     value:path.split(",")[0].replace("<d:URL>", ""),
     name: path.split(",")[1].replace("</d:URL>", "")
   }
 };
```

So your HTML will look like:

```
<a ng-href="{{path.URL.value}}" target="_blank">{{path.URL.name}}</a>
```

Comment: he has `$scope.paths` so seems like he have to do transforming array of strings to objects with name and value - it's double iterative operation: `map`, `repeat` and also it consumes additional memory for objects like: `{name: "google", value: "https://google.com"}` which in current case not needed.

Comment: @num8er hhh, I didn't find  `$scope.paths`